# How can I correctly index elements in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, data-mining

I am trying to implement the following function to train a neural network as below:

```
        # Here I am trying to convert train edges to nx.graph

       data.edge_index = torch.from_numpy(edges(data._train)).long()
        G = nx.Graph()
        edge_numpy = data.edge_index.numpy()
        edge_list = []

        for i in range(data.num_edges):
        edge_list.append(tuple(edge_numpy[:, i]))
    G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
    data.G = G

    # These are nodes from training graph
    nodes = list(G.nodes())

    new = []

    # These are features for the whole graph
    feature = data.x.detach().cpu().numpy()

    # Here the all set is calculated from all nodes in whole graph
    all = get_seedsets(data.num_nodes, c=0.5)
    print(all)..... [array([5, 1, 2]), array([1])]

    for i in range(len(all)):
        temp_id = all[i]
        specific_features=np.zeros((feature.shape[0], feature.shape[1])

        # Here I am trying to copy features of each node in the all to specific_features
        for v in range(len(nodes)):
            y = nodes.index(v).........*ValueError: 180 is not in list*

            if y in temp_id:
                specific_features[nodes[v]] = feature[y]
```

However, I am getting this error:

> V`alueError: 180 is not in list*

What can I do?

Comment: In your own words: what values are you expecting `v` to have, each time through the loop? What values are you expecting the list to contain? What do you expect `nodes.index(v)` to mean? In particular, what should happen if you do `nodes.index(v)` and `v` is equal to 180?

Comment: here i am expecting  a specific node of the graph @peter

Comment: Is the indentation really as shown here? E.g. the first line of code seems out of whack. And the first line after the first `for` loop seems to be incorrect as well.

Comment: just a typing error, these two lines must align with the for loop
    G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
    data.G = G

Comment: @PeterMortensen